# How to submit a HTML form with header

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to submit a form including a header during posting the request , is that possible ? 
I tried below code but I was unable to send the request with the defined header .

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Myheader" , "value")
  </script>
    <form action="https://example.com/myprofile/myedit" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Jacob&#32;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="jacob&#64;gmail&#46;com" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to submit a form including a header during posting the request , is that possible ?

No.

You can only add custom HTTP headers to a request if you are using XMLHttpRequest or fetch to make the request (so you can't if you are using a form submission to make the request).

You could use the `submit` event to intercept the form submission and make the request with XMLHttpRequest or fetch instead … but then you'd need to handle the response with JS too.

Comment: so it is not possible to add a HTTP header like 'Content-Type' with XMLHttpRequest !! is there any other possibilities

Comment: @Coder13 — It's entirely possible to do that. I said that in the second paragraph of this answer! You just have to make the HTTP request using XMLHttpRequest. You can't use XMLHttpRequest to add a header to a form submission.

Comment: As far as i understood i have to make an http request and intercept and then add the header ? If yes can you please expand your answer with more explanation and code , thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: can you please provide me a working code for the same , i am confused reading the docs and not a pro with js