# How send back JWT to the server, using the header(in a web-app) using a form submit?

Tags: javascript, flask, jwt, http-headers, backend

I am working a on a web app[ back-end: python(`flask`) ]. I am using JWT to authorize the user (after simple login). The server, therefore, sends the JWT back to the browser as a custom response header `x-access-token`. Now I have to allow(only the authorized ones) to be able to fill send data through form. This should involve the sending of **the same** JWT back to the server. After googling a lot, I found out that modifying the header is not possible(?) for the same request(re-sending a request using `$.ajax` will give me whole new token).
Additionally, we can not use `local-storage`, or similar technique(not "legal"). How should I go about modifying the header of the post request(made when form is submitted) so that it includes my JWT? Or is there any other way of sending back the token?

On the server side, POST is only possible when there is token attached to the header, `request.headers['x-access-token']` is present

```
@app.route("/upload",methods = ["POST"])
@token_required
def upload(current_user):
    ... Implementation of the post request when token is sent as a header....
```

On the client side, after login, jwt is sent and user is directed to other page with the following form [ response = form[in the body] + jwt[in header] ]:

```
  <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
   <div class="form-group"   >
       <input type="file"  name="file"></input>
         <input type="submit" value = "Upload" ></input>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to submit a HTML form with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459865/how-to-submit-a-html-form-with-header)

Comment: thanks jimmy, so this is not possible right? But how does jwt aurtherization work then, I wonder.

Comment: In a sense; it's not possible strictly through HTML, you'll need to add some JavaScript to handle the request and add the JWT to the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 0):

To send the JWT back to the server from a client side jQuery ajax request you need to include the "withCredentials: true" value to the "xhrFields" option of the request.   The @token_required decorator can then act as the view protector as you desire.

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.